# How to find and delete products in magento that have no image

Tags: products-management

Can anyone help me find products that have no images assigned to them.

Either a list of products with no images or a way to delete them using a PHP script would be ideal

Thank you

Comment: I assume you are talking about the image gallery images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('media_gallery', array('isnull' => true))
```

should give you all the products.

```
$collection->delete();
```

should delete them all.

**But be careful, if the filter is wrong, you might delete all products!**

Comment: There is no delete() on a collection unless you implement it yourself, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7820188

Comment: I'm sorry, there is, here: `\Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract::delete()`

Comment: Oh well... spent too much time in Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract it seems ;-) It's funny that one class has it implemented and not the other.

Comment: Absolutely, should be moved up in the inheritance chain ! :)